# ggplot2: Plot 2 graphs with overlapping x axis values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Hi, I have two data frames with the following frequency/percentage values.

```
Value  Frequency Percentage
2         1   2.777778
3         7  19.444444
4        19  52.777778
5         9  25.000000


Value Frequency Percentage
1         2   3.773585
2         3   5.660377
3         8  15.094340
4        20  37.735849
5        20  37.735849
```

As you can see the values belong to the same range 1-5. But in some cases, some values don't have a frequency (The value 1 is missing in df 1). How can I plot the percentage values in the same graph using 2 geom_lines? I want both lines to have a common x axis from 1-5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1<-data.frame(Value = c(2,3,4,5),
                Frequency = c(1,7,19,9),
                Percentage = c(2.777778,19.444444,52.777778,25.000000)
                )

 df2<-data.frame(Value = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 Frequency = c(2,3,8,20,20),
                 Percentage = c(3.773585,5.660377,15.094340,37.735849,37.735849
                 ))               

df1$N<-factor(1)
df2$N<-factor(2)

df3<-rbind(df1,df2)

library(ggplot2)

plot<-ggplot(df3,aes(Value,Percentage, color = N))+
  geom_line()
print(plot)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iua2d.png

Comment: When I tried it, the x axis was ordered as 2,3,4,5,1. What have I done wrong?

Comment: [to clarify] I only renamed my dataframes and used the code, but it says "Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?" So I used group=N. Only then the plot is created, but the ordering 2,3,4,5,1 is there. When I use your code as it is, there is no problem.

Comment: Maybe in your data frames the Value variable is an ordered factor??. Use class(df3$Value)

Answer (score 0):

You can row bind both data sets, create a tag variable, to identify the two data sets and then plot

```
df1 = data.frame(Value = c(2,3,4,5),
                 Frequency = c(1,7,19,9),
                 Percentage = c(2.77,19.44,52.77,25))
df2 = data.frame(Value = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 Frequency = c(2,3,8,20,20),
                 Percentage = c(3.77,5.66,15.09,37.73,37.73))

df1$Type = "A"
df2$Type = "B"

dfw = rbind(df1,df2)

ggplot(data = dfw, aes(x = Value, y = Percentage, color = Type)) + geom_line()
```